# Как найти и экспортировать ветки реестра содержащие определенное значение в ключах?

Tags: windows-7, реестр

В общем нужно перенести с одного реестра на одном ПК в другой реестр другого ПК такие ветки, которые содержат определенное слово или фразу или предложение и т.д.

Например по фразе "Рамамбахарамамбуру" находит ветку

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Patches\1CB0F51845E7C003A9AC9C64F0FDF687\SourceList\Net
```

и еще пару-тройку сотен.

Что как и чем сделать так, чтоб можно было эти ветки экспортировать, а на другом ПК импортировать одним файлом?

Нашел программу `reg organizer` - можно осуществить поиск, высвечиваются все ветки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но, к сожалению, их можно только удалить)))

Есть ли какие-то такие супер программы с поиском и экспортом конкретных веток?
Или как чем такое вообще можно провернуть? Что использовать?

Comment: Я бы нашёл список ключей программно (на C# должно быть в десяток строк), экспортировал их, а на той стороне импортировал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскребя в интернете по мануалам команд батника сделал такую программку:

```
@echo OFF

set counter=0
setlocal enableextensions enableDelayedExpansion

set TEMP_FOLDER_DIR=%temp%\regParts
set SECTION_LIST=(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,HKEY_CURRENT_USER,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,HKEY_USERS,HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG)

if [%1]==[] (set KEY_NAME=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications) else (set KEY_NAME=%1)
if [%2]==[] (set VALUE_NAME="Internet Explorer") else (set VALUE_NAME=%2)
if [%3]==[] (set TMP_EXPORT=%TEMP_FOLDER_DIR%) else (set TMP_EXPORT=%3)
if [%4]==[] (set DEST_MEEGED_FILE=%userprofile%\desktop) else (set DEST_MEEGED_FILE=%4)

if not exist %TEMP_FOLDER_DIR% mkdir "%TEMP_FOLDER_DIR%"

for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-2*" %%a in (`reg query %KEY_NAME% /f %VALUE_NAME% /s  2^>nul`)  do (
    set ValueName=%%a
    set ValueType=%%b
    set ValueValue=%%c  

    set TRUE=

    if defined ValueName (      
        FOR %%G IN %SECTION_LIST% DO (          
            if not "!ValueName!"=="!ValueName:%%G=!" (
                set TRUE=1              
            )
        )               

        if defined TRUE (
            set /a counter=counter+1
            echo !counter! - !ValueName!
            c:\Windows\SysWOW64\reg.exe export !ValueName! "%TMP_EXPORT%\test!counter!.reg" 
        )
    )
)

copy /b "%TMP_EXPORT%\*.reg" "%DEST_MEEGED_FILE%\mergedFile.reg"
rmdir %TEMP_FOLDER_DIR% /s /q

endlocal
pause
```

где можно передать входные параметры:

```
1 - раздел где ищем
2 - значение, которое ищем
3 - временная папка для всех найденных веток
4 - финальная папка, где будет хранится общий файл со всеми слитыми кусками
usebackq  - возможность командного исполнения того, что заключено в обратные кавычки
tokens - Задает элементы, передаваемые из каждой строки в тело цикла for 
         при каждой итерации. В результате "tokens=1-2*" мы получаем название ключа, 
         тип и значение ключа в ветке итерации
```

По умолчанию при отсутствии какого либо параметра ищет в `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications` (HKLM - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE), строку `Internet Explorer`, складирует куски в `temp` директорию, а окончательный результат кладет на рабочий стол

Answer (score 2):

Например, можно воспользоваться такой несложной программой:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Run();
    }

    const bool Use64BitView = true;
    const string needle = "Рамамбахарамамбуру";

    void Run()
    {
        var hives = new[]
        {
            RegistryHive.ClassesRoot,
            RegistryHive.Users,
            RegistryHive.LocalMachine
        };
        CreateCommonRegistryScript(
            hives.SelectMany(GetMatchingKeys), путь-к-вашему-файлу.reg);
    }

    IEnumerable<string> GetMatchingKeys(RegistryHive hive)
    {
        var regView = Use64BitView ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32;
        using (var root = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(hive, regView))
        {
            foreach (var name in FilterRec(root))
                yield return name;
        }
    }

    void CreateCommonRegistryScript(IEnumerable<string> paths, string outPath)
    {
        var tmpFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
        var regAccess = Use64BitView ? "/reg:64" : "/reg:32";

        try
        {
            var first = true;
            foreach (var path in paths)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Processing: {path}");
                Process.Start("reg", $"export \"{path}\" \"{tmpFileName}\" /y {regAccess}")
                       .WaitForExit();
                var lines = File.ReadLines(tmpFileName);
                if (first)
                    File.WriteAllLines(outPath, lines);
                else
                    File.AppendAllLines(outPath, lines.Skip(1));
                first = false;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            File.Delete(tmpFileName);
        }
    }

    bool ContainsIgnoreCase(string haystack, string needle)
    {
        return haystack.IndexOf(needle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }

    bool IsKeyGood(RegistryKey key)
    {
        if (ContainsIgnoreCase(key.Name, needle))
            return true;
        string[] valueNames;
        try
        {
            valueNames = key.GetValueNames();
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException)
        {
            // ?
            return false;
        }
        return valueNames.Any(name => CheckValue(key, name));
    }

    bool CheckValue(RegistryKey key, string name)
    {
        if (ContainsIgnoreCase(name, needle))
            return true;
        var kind = key.GetValueKind(name);
        switch (kind)
        {
        case RegistryValueKind.String:
            var value = (string)key.GetValue(name);
            if (ContainsIgnoreCase(value, needle))
                return true;
            break;
        case RegistryValueKind.MultiString:
            var values = (string[])key.GetValue(name);
            if (values.Any(v => ContainsIgnoreCase(v, needle)))
                return true;
            break;
        case RegistryValueKind.ExpandString:
            var unexpandedValue = (string)key.GetValue(name, null,
                    RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames);
            if (ContainsIgnoreCase(unexpandedValue, needle))
                return true;
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    IEnumerable<string> FilterRec(RegistryKey root)
    {
        if (IsKeyGood(root))
            yield return root.Name;
        string[] subkeyNames;
        try
        {
            subkeyNames = root.GetSubKeyNames();
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException)
        {
            // ?
            yield break;
        }
        foreach (var subkeyName in subkeyNames)
        {
            using (var key = root.OpenSubKey(subkeyName))
            {
                if (key == null)
                    continue; // ?
                foreach (var name in FilterRec(key))
                    yield return name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Она обходит реестр рекурсивно и находит все ключи, имена которых, имена значений которых, или значения в которых содержат заданную подстроку. Список ключей скармливается стандартной утилите `reg` по одному, а она уж генерирует скрипт, который программа сливает в один файл.

На моей машине работает, хотя я не уверен, что ловлю все нужные исключения.

Возможно, нужно добавить ещё хайвы.

Comment: А говорили десяток строк))) Спасибо за ответ.. Сам я через батник сделал.... Ваш код попозже попробую, посмотрю как работает

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Ну в общем-то ядро всего — функция `FilterRec`, она вроде недлинная (ещё если проверку ошибок выкинуть...)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Вроде правильно «Рамамба...», а не «Рахамба...». Исправил в коде.

Comment: Да, я просто непомню как точно)) Тоже исправил)) ...Закончил испытания вашего кода. Вроде работает. Как я понял в `OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.ClassesRoot` должно быть `OpenBaseKey(hive` ? ))) А то как-то странно LINQ смотрится)) 
Правда у меня лично при ключах `LocalMachine` и `Users` в методе `FilterRec` выбивает ошибку по `security` в строке `using (var key = root.OpenSubKey(subkeyName))`..... у себя то я обработал..работает теперь....
но на всякий случай сообщаю.....а может у меня каких-то прав не хватает, хотя я и администратор у себя на компе.....

Comment: и еще маленькая мелочь - не ищет при значении пути...например `"c:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer"` в случае если буква диска маленькая, а не большая........
Размеры реестров из моего батника и вашей программы различаются))... только по `HKU` почти одинаково.....кому верить)))  из-за разницы даже не знаю чей ответ ближе, чтоб принять. Этот вопрос видимо надо намного глубже изучать, чтоб понять...........
Пока кусты реестра, скачанные своим батником влил, ничего не сбойнуло, функционирует......но +1 точно пока с меня....... почему я C# не рассматривал с самого начала - не знаю)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Тьфу, точно, `hive`. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: сравнение можно сделать case insensitive, момент // сделал.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: По поводу размера реестров, попробуйте `Use64BitView = false` для интереса. А где размер больше?

Comment: У меня больше........))) хехехе....... но все же это не показатель, наверное....надо сделать сравнительный анализ....и,как я написал выше, сам вопрос глубже ...........да, без `Use64BitView = false` размер увеличивается, как раз почти догоняя мои батники... отдельно HKLM даже больше.....а в чем подвох?  Я почти понимаю...И я почти понимаю почему сумма отдельных файлы HKLM,HKU,HKCR больше чем в файле с общими данными по трем ключам сразу

Comment: Ну, реестр виртуализирован, и у 64-битные приложения видят другой контент, не такой, как 32-битные. Конкретным типом доступа можно управлять. (HKCU, понятно, подможество HKU.)

Comment: С таким количеством кода можно было добавить обработку командной строки...

Comment: @Discord: Это да, но я решил оставить это в качестве упражнения. Иначе придётся подключать фреймворк по разбору командной строки (а нормальных вроде бы нету) или писать велосипед.

Comment: @VladD Чтобы сделать несколько позиционных аргументов, фреймворк не нужен. :) Вон, как в батнике.

Comment: @Discord: Пожалуй. Но всё равно это бы утяжелило и так слишком тяжёлый для такой простой задачи код.

Answer (score -1):

Стандартная программа реестра regedit. 
Экспорт/Импорт.

Comment: Там нет функции такой, чтоб можно было сразу все ветки с ключевым словом скопом найти и экспортировать. Только по одной ветке.... А если их несколько сотен?))

Comment: Тогда стандартная консольная программа reg.  
 
        reg quier /v <параметр>

   
         reg export

Comment: Только не `/v "param"` а `/f "my value" /s` ....... однако это только найдет по значению........ для экспорта нужно знать полный путь...... а это сводится к тому, что нужно опять по одному экспортировать........ а нужно сразу все что нашел экспортнуть........может быть я не всё прочитал или понял.. вы бы лучше пример написали бы в своем ответе как правильно будет